# looking for api/protocol over http

Tags: java, http, frameworks, jaxb, protocols

I want to design a protocol between several components I have. each can run in separate process on a different host. There is always an initiator (client) and someone who respond (server). the client might be in several languages java/c#/c++/cli. The server in my case is always in java.
So I thought about the following properties:

- It should by plain text so it will be easy to debug.
- It should allow upgrade seemplessly of one side (it means no class serialization and no strict method signatures).
- If it is a framework, the in should be thin (WSDL looks too much for my needs).

I thought using http over tcp.
I am interested mostly in the syntax and if there are frameworks in java which already provides such capabilities. I remember vaguely that there is something like that in `Spring`.

**EDIT**: I prefer a thin framework, and also I am afraid that changing method signature in RPC will cause competability problems.
I found [this example](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Designing_a_client_server_protocol_in_XML.html) and it might feet my needs as I am already using `jaxb`.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a "Remote Procedure Call" (RPC) aka "Remote (Method) Invocation" (RI/RMI). I suggest you read up on it and examine some frameworks and pick the one that suits you most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP). While not the easiest, there are various libraries on nearly all language/platform combinations and it is quite extendible.
XML-RPC might also be suggested, but SOAP is its successor so I'd recommend against using XML-RPC.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into REST/ful services:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html

The linked article also discusses a few guidelines, when SOAP and when REST is more applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with WSDL. It's actually meant to establish remote communication between components written in various languages. I've been using it under heavy load with C#, PHP, C++, Python and Java for long time and it was great.
Basically, all what you will have to do, is to actually design a real protocol, which WSDL is not itself - the protocol in this case would be set of commands on the top of WSDL, e.g. Hello Command (some sort of ping), the Login and Logout commands (for session), then all sorts of stuff you need.

Comment: WebServices are always OK. You can start from Apache CXF, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could stay on TCP level and use some intelligent library like [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) to handle all the wiring. The protocol itself then is a just set of messages and tailorable to your requirements (and as with WSDLs not predetermined by the transport infrastructure).

Example (I challenge the WebService proponents to fit an example in their answers ;)

The server (python for brevity):

```py
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:12345')
while True:
    message = socket.recv()
    # 'status' and 'shutdown server' would be part of your protocol
    if message == "status":
        socket.send("I'm ok")
    elif message == "shutdown server":
        socket.send("Ok, bye bye")
        break
    # implement your other commands here ...
socket.close()
```

A client:

```
import zmq
ctx = zmq.Context()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:12345')
socket.send('shutdown server')
reply = socket.recv()
print(reply)
```

That's it. And yes, zeromq comes with 30+ language bindings.